# command dump is not found in crontab

Tags: linux, centos, backup, cron

I am using CentOS and trying to perform a backup of my /home directory using crontab.

When I run my dump command in the terminal it works fine but when I try to run it using crontab it does not run.

This is my command: (runs once a week, Friday at 8pm)

```
0 20 * * 5 dump -0f /Mt/home.bck /home
```

Why doesn't it run?

When I look at the log file of cron it says:

```
(root) CMD (dump -0f /Mt/home.bck /home)
```

This message is printed every time the crotab is supposed to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because dump can't be found in the environment in which cron is running,

Answer (score 0):

You should always start by looking at the logs. In CentOS, cron stores logs to /var/log/cron. Try `less +F /var/log/cron` to see where the actual error is, then report back here what the real error was!

Comment: When I look at the log file of cron it says: (root) CMD (dump -0f /Mt/home.bck /home)

This message repeats every time the crotab is supposed to execute

Comment: Then @Fred Mitchell's answer is probably correct. Add the full path to `dump`

Comment: How to I check dump's full PATH? I tried to google it but I was not able to find it.